# Ajuda com sons em LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx

Estou utilizando esta biblioteca para jogos , e queria saber como eu poderia fazer para colocar sons para tocarem durante o jogo e com tempo pré definido?

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Streaming-music

Comment: como assim tempo pré definido ?

Comment: definir , por exemplo , daqui a 5 segundos tocar uma musica , daqui a mais 5 segundos tocar outra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando estou desenvolvendo aplicações de áudio para *android* é inevitável o uso de threads, as `threads` permitem executar funções de maneira concorrente, um exemplo é a utilização do [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html), para execução de maneira assíncrona é de longe a minha preferida, você ainda pode utilizar um [Handle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) para executar tarefas scheduladas(agendadas) em background.

Um exemplo simples de como agendar um áudio para tocar a cada 500 mili-segundos utilizando threads seria:

```
Sound sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("ederwander.mp3"));
final Handler ederhandler = new Handler();


//executa pela primeira vez e chama a thread para rodar em background
public void TocarAudio() {
        ederHandler.postDelayed(agendaAudio, 500);
}   

/**
* Executa thread em Background
* */

private Runnable agendaAudio = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {

              //Toca audio
              sound.play(1.0f);

              // thread será executado novamente após 500 mili segundos
              ederHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
           }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso ele cronometra 2 segundos e ativa algo, você pode ativar um som e parar, se quiser mais que 2 segundos só mudar o 2000, se quiser que só aconteça uma vez a cada chamada melhore o código adicionando um valor boolean :

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;

public class MeuScreen implements Screen{

public MeuScreen() {
        super();
        startTime = TimeUtils.millis();
    }



public void render(float delta) {
        //Isso vai fazer algo acontecer depois de 2 segundos 
        if (TimeUtils.millis()>(startTime+2000)){
            Gdx.app.log("Algo aconteceu", "");
        }

}
```